# gRaphael with Require JS

Tags: jquery, node.js, requirejs, gruntjs, graphael

I want use gRaphael and gline JS to draw chart using Require JS. 
Below is part of code I am implementing

```
paths: {
    jquery: '../bower_components/jquery/jquery',
    raphael: 'plugins/raphael',
    graphael: 'plugins/graphael',
    requirejs: '../bower_components/requirejs/require'
},
shim: {
    'raphael': {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: 'Raphael'
    },
    'graphael': {
        deps: ['raphael'],
        exports: 'gRaphael'
    },
    'gline': {
        deps: ['graphael'],
        exports: 'gLine'
    }
}
```

I am using it in another JS named chart.js as below :

```
define(['plugins/raphael','plugins/graphael','plugins/gline'], function(Raphael) {
   function Charts() {
      console.log("G Raphael Successfully loaded !");
   }
});
```

But when I compile and minify my code using grunt. 
I receieve following error:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: Raphael is not defined**